# Add event to Firefox when a specific url is loaded

Tags: javascript, url, firefox-addon

I'd like to write an extension that adds a div element to a page when a specific URL is loaded (e.g. when the url is http://www....&q=car&aq I'd like to have a div element containing "car" added to the webpage)

I'm already using addEventListener to check if a tab is open but I don't know how to do it for a specific URL.

p.s I'm not asking you guys to do my homework, only some links to tutorials speaking of this kind of tricks or basic examples d.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the url using the command `window.location` so you can do something like

```
if (window.location.indexof("http://www.yoururl.com") != -1 && !$.browser.msie)
{
    //add a div to the dom here.

}
```

This line !$.browser.msie is actually jquery, and might not compile incase you are not including jquery libraries, it basically checks for the browser version is not IE.

You can remove this part  -- && !$.browser.msie -- if you are not using jquery.

Comment: the question specifically asked about "firefox" thats the reason for the MSIE.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier for you to create a user script for [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/greasemonkey/). There is tons of documentation (e.g. in the [GreaseMonkey wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page)) and also lots of existing user scripts to look at on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/). A script can be "compiled" into a regular extension (see [User Script Compiler](http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler)).

If you want to stick with a real extension then you probably want to [register a progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs). This way you will know when the location of a tab changes:

```
onLocationChange: function(aBrowser, webProgress, request, location)
{
    if (location.host == "example.com")
        doSomething(aBrowser.contentDocument);
}
```